# Criar arquivo temporário usando C# e ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou interessado em gerar arquivos temporários em c#, asp.net e preciso da url temporária desse arquivo (HTML), esse arquivo não pode possuir um caminho físico no servidor devido ao acesso de várias pessoas. Sendo assim, não posso criar um arquivo para cada acesso. Creio que esses sejam temporários, queria a ajuda de alguém, por onde começo a procurar sobre este assunto.

Comment: Qual o objetivo desta geração?

Comment: Cigano o objetivo seria gerar boletos, como o boleto é por usuário, eu não posso criar arquivo por arquivo no servidor, lembrando que quero estudar o assunto pois estou aprendendo.

Comment: @user6901, neste caso você não precisa implementar nada novo, basta usar uma view com a Template Engine da sua preferência, como o Razor.

Comment: agradeço TobyMosque, vou procurar sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que para seguir neste caminho você irá enfrentar alguns problemas, em todo caso eu tenho algumas sugestões.

Para devolver o arquivo `HTML` ao usuário, você pode converter a `string` para `byte[]` e devolver um `FileResult` como `mine-type` `text/html`:

```
public FileResult Index()
{
    var model = new
    {
        guid = Guid.NewGuid(),
        nome = "Toby Mosque"
    };
    var html = $@"
        <div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    GUID:
                    <input id='guid' type='text' value='{model.guid}' />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    Nome:
                    <input id='nome' type='text' value='{model.nome}' />
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    ";

    var binary = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
    return File(binary, "text/html");
}
```

Note que no nosso exemplo acima o modelo tem um identificador único, então nós podemos armazenar o binário do arquivo no Cache e usar o `GUID` como chave.

```
MemoryCache.Default.Add(model.guid.ToString(), binary, new CacheItemPolicy
{
    Priority = CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
    AbsoluteExpiration = MemoryCache.InfiniteAbsoluteExpiration,
    SlidingExpiration = MemoryCache.NoSlidingExpiration
});
```

claro que em um ambiente de produção não é desejável ter um Cache com prioridade extrema e que nunca expira, então configure o mesmo com carinho.

então quando chamar esta controller, você pode verificar se o binário acima existe no cache e não irá precisar criar o mesmo novamente.

```
var binary = default(byte[]);
if (MemoryCache.Default.Contains(model.guid.ToString()))
{
    binary = MemoryCache.Default.Get(model.guid.ToString()) as byte[];
}
else
{
    var html = string.Empty;
    /* Logica de montagem do HTML aqui  */
    binary = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
}
return File(binary, "text/html");
```

Lembrando que para utilizar o [`MemoryCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) é necessário adicionar o Assembly [`System.Runtime.Caching`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching(v=vs.110).aspx) ao seu projeto.

porém se os seus templates forem um pouco mais complexos, você pode usar o [`Handlebars.NET`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Handlebars.Net/), neste caso o seu `html` vai dá origem á uma `Function<string, object>`.

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(html))
{
    var hbTemplate = Handlebars.Compile(reader);
    var stream = hbTemplate.template(model);
    return File.Stream(stream, "text/html");
}
```

neste caso, é desejável que você mantenha os seus `templates` compilados no Cache.

Para saber mais sobre a sintaxe do `Handlebars`, pode olhar o site da versão dele para `JavaScript`:

[`HandlebarsJS`](http://handlebarsjs.com)

Comment: Faltou apenas você explicar de onde veio aquele `MemoryCache`.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, falha minha, corrigido.